# Package 'com.sun.webkit.dom' is declared in module 'javafx.web', which does not export it to module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9

Trying to move from `Java 8` to `Java 9`, and I get this error

> Package 'com.sun.webkit.dom' is declared in module 'javafx.web', which
>   does not export it to module.

How do I fix this so that the Pre-compiler (Intellij) and run-time that I don't get this or what is a good replacement for `com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl`.

Comment: This might help [Removed or Changed APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.webkit=ALL-UNAMED`

To your VM options or Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, but it didn't work for me. I tried various things and looked around. https://nipafx.dev/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/ was helpful in understanding more about modules. In the end, running on intellij, adding this got it to work:

```
--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I had to explicitly include the full package.